# How to make Angular 11 i18n work in NRWL NX workspace.json?

Tags: angular, internationalization, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Angular 11 has built-in support for [i18n](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). This works great when configure in `angular.json` config file.
I am working on large project where there are multiple sub-project in single monorepo. We are using Nrwl NX `workspace.json` to configure the projects.
Problem is that `workspace.json` has different syntax regarging the i18n, and it does not seem to be compatible with that of `angular.json`. Also the NX documentation is very brief (almost not existent) regarging the i18n.

Result is that currently my app is not localized at all.

Any ideas how to make i18n work inside NRWL NX?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the record: here is the link on bug report on missing documentation https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4751

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After several tries I have found a way how to make it work.

So there are several steps how to make Angular's i18n work within NRWL NX workspace.

**Step #1) Define multiple locales in default build target**

```
"targets": {
  "build": {
    "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
        // … options not relevant to i18n removed
        "i18nMissingTranslation": "warning",
        "localize": ["fr", "en", "sp"]
    },
```

**Step #2) Define named build targets for each locale**

```
"configurations": {
   "production": {
     // ... some prod settings
   },
   "en": {
     "localize": ["en"]
   },
   "fr": {
     "localize": ["fr"]
   }
  },
```

**Step #3) Update serve configuration to use specific build target**
Notice the `appname:build:en` - that instructs nx serve to use specific build target

```
"serve": {
 "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
 "options": {
   "browserTarget": "appname:build:en"
 }
}
```

**Step #4) Run nx serve to verify its working**

Full article with more details is here - http://blog.davidjs.com/2021/03/working-with-angular-i18n-inside-nrwl-nx-workspace/